# Cassandra data not distributed evenly

Tags: cassandra

I have a 3 node cluster with a replication factor of 3. `nodetool status` shows that one node has 100gb of data, another 90gb, and another 30gb. Each node owns 100% of the data.

I'm using a unique url as my clustering key, so I would imagine data should be spread around evenly. Even such, since RF is 3 all nodes should contain the same amount of data. Any ideas what's going on?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the partition key of your table ?

Comment: You have 3 node and RF is 3 for all the keyspace ? Why ?

Comment: The partition key is a unique url. I'm using a simple primary key.

Answer (score 0):

What is the write consistency level being used? I guess it might be  "consistency one" and hence data would get eventually replicated. Especially if the data was dumped in one shot. Try to use "consistency local_quorum" to avoid this issue in future.

Try running a "nodetool repair" and it should bring the data back in sync in all nodes.

*Remember the writes from "cqlsh" are by default with "consistency one".*

Comment: Writes are quorum. One node did go down for a bit. I've ran `nodetool repair` but nothing changed.